# Creating DLL files in C#

Tags: c#, dll

When creating DLL files for a program that already exists, is it customary to create them by going to

File > 
New > 
Project > 
Class Library,

File > 
Add > 
New Project > 
Class Library,

or

File > 
Add > 
Existing Project > 
Class Library?

Comment: You might want to gather some info on what is a "dll" first before throwing in such questions :)

Comment: It is customary to add the project to the solution which creates the program.  Makes it easy to debug.  It is quite unclear whether or not you have such a solution.

Comment: @ Hans Passant - My apologies for not being more clear.  I have a project I have completed from a previous assignment.  My task is to take that project and create DLL files for it and then reference them.  The textbook I have discusses creating DLL files, then creating the source code and then the references - completely the opposite of what I need to do.  It has two seperate projects, one for the DLL files and the other for the source code.  This didn't square with what I remember the professor saying so I thought it best to ask before going further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should differentiate 2 things:

1. DLLs - compiled code in machine (in case of .net, clr) readable format for execution
2. Code - source code files that get compiled into DLLs.

If you have a dll that you can use, you add it as a reference to your project. 
If you have source codes, you can add them the way you specified (add existing project). If you want to write new .dll, you should use "Create new class library". Note that whenever you add through "Add existing project", project (along with source codes) isn't copied to your solution folder.

Basics you should know before you go on:

1. Solution - means to tie several projects together into one logical bunch.
2. Project - means to tie several source code files/resources/etc. into one logical bunch that gets compiled into one physical unit - dll/exe/etc.
3. Source file - code file like MyClass.cs. This is where the code is written.
4. Reference - reference from one project to another one in order to obtain/use public-visible functionality.

I'd recommend reading some books on C#/.NET to get clearer understanding.

Comment: I have a textbook on C#/.NET.  The textbook shows DLL files being created via File > New > Project > Class Library.  However, it is creating the DLL files first, then writing the source code and referencing the DLL files.  However, my homework assignment is to take a project from a previous assignment, create DLL files and then reference them.  The book doesn't discuss this aspect of it.  That is why I am confused.

Comment: If you're having a project (class library I suppose) from previous assignment, once you compile it you get the DLL. Then you can create new class library and reference previously compiled project (as a dll).

Answer (score 2):

You are right, that is one way of creating dll,(for a class library in visual studio, you will get a dll) but its lot more than that. 
You should gather some knowledge for DLL check out this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx

Also check out this link how to create dll in c#
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie I have updated my answer to respond to ur needs

Answer (score 1):

Well what you have mentioned in your question is a good and simple way of creating DLL with C# (that is with  Class Library project) , further more you can direct your Compiler (csc.exe , it the Csharp compiler) with some commands to make a DLL for you,
Consider that you have few classes such as **Add.cs** (can Add numbers) **Mult.cs** (can multiply)

*To build the file MathLibrary.DLL,* you can use command like this

```
csc /target:library /out:MathLibrary.DLL Add.cs Mult.cs
```

The **/target:library** compiler option tells the compiler to output a DLL instead of an EXE file.
The **/out compiler** option followed by a file name is used to specify the DLL file name.

**P.S:** Solution derived from [How to: Create and Use C# DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**Referencing Custom Made DLL in C# Projects:**

1. Add a reference of the DLL
2. Add namespace in you project (or just start using DLL by fully qualified name)

**Snapshots**
[image: Add a reference of the DLL]
[image]